# Is the passive reference configuration different from the conventional direction of current?

Tags: electric-current, electrical-engineering

Is the passive reference configuration different from the conventional direction of current?

According to the passive reference configuration, current enters the positive polarity of voltage, while according to conversational current, electric current is said to move from the positive terminal to the negative. So do they differ in terms of current direction, or have I got something wrong? I was just expecting them to agree with each other.

Comment: It is just a matter of definition. Define current as the direction of positive charges or the direction of negative charges. As long as you keep it consistent you can do your calculations still.

Comment: The standard definition of the direction of the current (from "+" to "-") is from historical reasons. The electric charge was known even by the ancient Greek. Now, I quote from [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_charge#History)  *Franklin imagined electricity as being a type of invisible fluid present in all matter; . . . For a reason that was not recorded, he identified the term "positive" with vitreous electricity and "negative" with resinous electricity.* The electron wasn't known yet, and the current was considered as flowing from positive charges to negative.

Answer (score 2):

> according to conversational current, electric current is said to move from the positive terminal to the negative.

This is not correct.

The conventional current defines positive current in the direction of flow of positive charge, or opposite the direction of flow of negative charge.

But conventional current can flow either from a higher potential to a lower one, or from a lower potential to a higher potential. In fact, since current always flows in loops, it most flow both ways in any circuit.

For example, if you hook up a battery to a resistor, (conventional) current will be flowing from higher to lower potential through the resistor, but it will be flowing from lower to higher potential through the battery.

The reason for the passive reference convention is to keep track of how energy is flowing. If current is flowing from high to low potential then energy is being delivered to the device through which the current is flowing. If current is flowing from low potential to higher potential, then the device is delivering energy to the rest of the circuit. By using the passive reference convention to define the current direction for each individual device (or circuit branch) we can consistently define

$$P=IV$$

and have positive *P* indicate power delivered to the device, and negative *P* indicate power delivered by the device to the rest of the circuit.

Comment: Thanyou.....understood

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just asking for some clarification on terminology. Imagine a circuit which consists of only a resistor (passive component) connected across a battery (an active component). The end of the resistor connected to the battery's positive terminal will be it's positive end.

In the conventional current model, current flows out of the battery's positive end into the resistor's positive end. The term "passive reference configuration" is just a way of stating this, or letting you know the conventional current model is being used.